# Recording data as Audio through Android 3.5 mm jack

Tags: android, audio-recording

I am kind of a newbie and therefore I apologize if my question doesn't make a lot of sense. I wanted to build a cheap voltmeter for android. The idea is in it's infancy. What I wanted to know is whether it would be possible for me to record the voltage fluctuations from my device  via the 3.5 mm microphone jack.

Answer (score 0):

Typically for Android tablets and smartphones: the input line of the TRRS plug also serves as the power-supply for an external electret condenser microphone capsule, i.e. it is lifted to about 2.5V via a ca. 2kOhm resistor and the audible signal is decoupled via a condenser from further analog processing and A/D-conversion.

This way, any DC component of the input signal (and also very low frequencies) is kept away from the A/D-converter. Thus, your voltmeter will always show 0 Volt.

And slow fluctuations (= low frequencies) are filtered out by more than one high-pass filter. So, you would hardly find a device which is able to show frequencies below 10Hz but a lot more that have a smooth high-pass cutoff frequency of about 200-300Hz.